# JointJS diagram drawn in hidden div has wrong scale

Tags: html, svg, jointjs

I'm rendering a JointJS diagram in a div with visibility hidden. When I set the visibility to visible the shapes in the diagram are massive.

I can see in the code that each node is being scaled by calling:

```
box = this.node.getBBox()
```

But this is returning an empty object (presumably because the node is hidden). The width/height are then defaulted to zero. Later on the node is being scaled as follows:

`scalable.attr('transform', 'scale(' + (size.width / (scalableBbox.width || 1)) + ',' + (size.height / (scalableBbox.height || 1)) + ')');`

Since the returned scalableBbox has width 0 the result of (size.width / (scalableBbox.width || 1)) is the width and the node is therefore scaled to its width * width / 1. The same happens for the height.

This seems wrong!

Is there any way to render a JointJS diagram in an invisible div or is there a way to redraw the diagram once the div becomes visible?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever find a solution to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `scalable` class from your element shape to avoid this issue.

The scale feature is only used during resize: [documentation](http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Element:resize)

You can define your own shape without scalable element: [tutorial](http://jointjs.com/tutorial#custom-elements)